# Jquery autocomplete not populating in other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

**Scenario:** 
I have a drop down list where a user can select a supplier. Based on the supplier they have selected, the user can search for an item using the paper search (using JQuery Autocomplete). When an item is selected, the `description`, `price` and `per_pack` text boxes are populated with the relevant information for that particular item (this information is pulled from my database).

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

**Problem:**
When the user selects an item from the paper search, the text boxes stated above are not being populated with the relevant information and i have no idea as to why that is occurring. Does anyone know why that is?

**This is the code for the paper search:**

```
$(function() {
window.globalVar = 0;

// Skip the filled description boxes
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if($('#description_'+window.globalVar).val() != "")
    {
        window.globalVar++;
    }
}

// Write the paper description and price for the selected paper
function log( message ) {
    var values = message.split('|');
    $('#description_'+window.globalVar).val(values[0]);
    $('#priceper_'+window.globalVar).val(values[1]);
$('#per_pack_'+window.globalVar).val(values[2]);
    window.globalVar++;
    console.log(window.globalVar);
}

// Search the Paper db
$( "#supplier_search" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mpc.vario/mis_pp/common/pp_json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 25,
        name_startsWith: request.term,
        supplier: $('#supplier').val()
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.name + '|' + item.value + '|' + item.pack
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item.value );
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
  },
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-stop" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
});
 });
```

**This is the code for adding/deleting rows:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $counter = 1;
    $('#buttonadd').click(function () {
        $counter++;
        $('#invoiceitems > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="button" class="buttondelete" value="Delete"/></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][description]" id="description_" class="description" size="85" maxlength="70" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][priceper]" id="description_" class="priceper" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][per_pack]" id="per_pack_" class="per_pack" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][quantity]" id="quantity_" class="quantity" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><label class="subtotal"></label></td></tr>');

    });
    $('table#invoiceitems').on('keyup', '.quantity , .priceper',function () {
        UpdateTotals(this);
    });

    $counter = 1;
       $('table#invoiceitems').on('click','.buttondelete',function () {
        $counter++;
        if($('table#invoiceitems tbody tr').length==1){
            alert('Cant delete single row');
            return false;
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    });
    CalculateSubTotals();
    CalculateTotal();
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying the problem is that after deleting an item, the values don't go into the textboxes when adding an item?  Or are you saying that after deleting an item, the values get screwed up?

Comment: I think i didn't explain myself well :S before i integrated the add and delete features i was able to select an item from the paper search and the values would appear in the text boxes with ease. However, after modifying my code so that i am able to enable the user to delete and add more items the values no longer appear in the text boxes. If i select an item from my search, nothing happens @ovaherenow

Comment: @rache_r please add your javascript for adding and deleting rows

Comment: Please find code for adding and deleting rows above @CSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as the population of the detail fields is dependent on the "row number" (via window.globalVar)

Make sure that you re-calculate the "active" row whenever you delete and add new line items.

The code that is setting the values of the fields is this section:

```
 $('#description_'+window.globalVar).val(values[0]);
 $('#priceper_'+window.globalVar).val(values[1]);
 $('#per_pack_'+window.globalVar).val(values[2]);
```

Debug your javascript and check the value of `window.globalVar` at the time you select and item from the drop-down list. You will most likely find that the value is incorrect and you are trying to set the value of a control that does not exist in the document.

Comment: is this so that the totals are updated for when adding and deleting new line items? @CSL

Comment: @rache_r Firefox has an excellent plug-in called Firebug but I tend to use Google Chrome - simply press F12 when on your page and it opens up a window with a script debugger amongst other things. You can set breakpoints, watches etc.

Comment: on google chrome dev tools when i go on the console section, all that shows is array[25] and then the number 11. @CSL

Comment: @rache_r the number 11 most likely comes from this line console.log(window.globalVar) - therefore do you have a control with id='#description_11' in your document?

Comment: i don't have a control with id='#description_11' @CSL

Comment: @rache_r Then that is your issue, your code is trying to update the description, price and price per pack for controls that do not exist on the page. You need to tidy up the logic around the row tracking so that your code points to valid controls.

Comment: oh ok. Correct me if i am wrong, so i need to tidy up the code so that it sets the value to a control that actually exists in my document? If  so, is there anything in particular you could particularly suggest that will help me further correct this issue. @CSL

Answer (score 0):

`window.globalVar`was indeed trying to set its value to a control that did not exist.

**updated code that works:**

```
    $(function() {
    window.globalVar = 1;

    // Write the paper description and price for the selected paper
    function log( message ) {
        var values = message.split('|');
        $('#description_'+window.globalVar).val(values[0]);
        $('#priceper_'+window.globalVar).val(values[1]);
    $('#per_pack_'+window.globalVar).val(values[2]);
        console.log(window.globalVar);
    }

    // Search the Paper db
    $( "#supplier_search" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://mpc.vario/mis_pp/common/pp_json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 25,
            name_startsWith: request.term,
            supplier: $('#supplier').val()
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.name + '|' + item.value + '|' + item.pack
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item.value );
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-stop" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $counter = 1;
    $('#buttonadd').click(function () {
        $counter++;
        $('#invoiceitems > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="button" class="buttondelete" value="Delete"/></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][description]" id="description_' + $counter + '" class="description" size="85" maxlength="70" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][priceper]" id="priceper_' + $counter + '" class="priceper" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][per_pack]" id="per_pack_' + $counter + '" class="per_pack" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" name="item[' + $counter + '][quantity]" id="quantity_' + $counter + '" class="quantity" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>\
        <td><label class="subtotal"></label></td></tr>');
    window.globalVar = $counter;

    });
    $('table#invoiceitems').on('keyup', '.quantity , .priceper',function () {
        UpdateTotals(this);
    });

    $counter = 1;
       $('table#invoiceitems').on('click','.buttondelete',function () {
        $counter++;
        if($('table#invoiceitems tbody tr').length==1){
            alert('Cant delete single row');
            return false;
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    UpdateTotals(this);

    });
    CalculateSubTotals();
    CalculateTotal();
    });
```